# Grub 2, changing shift button

Tags: linux, button, ubuntu-10.04, shift, grub

I'm new to linux and bash, so I don't know what am I doing wrong. I set up grub to don't show, and show after pushing shift for 3 seconds. This worked fine. Then I changed line in 30_os-prober (as you can see underneath) which contained 'shift' to 'F11' as I read here: http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html (13.3.33). Now when I press F11 nothing happens, and when I press shift I can see 'Grub is loading', then default OS (Ubuntu) loads without showing grub menu.

This is part of my /etc/default/grub content:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT="Custom Menu"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" splash vga=799 quiet"
```

and this is (IMHO) crucial part, from /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober:

```
adjust_timeout () {
  #if [ "x${found_other_os}" = "x" ] ; then
    if [ "x${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT}" != "x" ] ; then
      if [ "x${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET}" = "xtrue" ] ; then
    verbose=
      else
    verbose=" --verbose"
      fi

      if [ "x${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT}" = "x0" ] ; then
    cat <<EOF
if [ \${timeout} != -1 ]; then
  if keystatus; then
    if keystatus --F11; then << There I changed shift to F11
      set timeout=-1
    else
      set timeout=0
    fi
  else
    if sleep$verbose --interruptible 3 ; then
      set timeout=0
    fi
  fi
fi
EOF
      else
    cat << EOF
if [ \${timeout} != -1 ]; then
  if sleep$verbose --interruptible ${GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT} ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
EOF
      fi
    fi
  #fi
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The keystatus documentation at the link you provided (and other keystatus documentation that I've come across) indicates that it accepts only --shift --ctrl or --alt as key-specific parameters.  Perhaps it does not work for other keys such as F11.

The other thing to be aware of is that keystatus apparently does not work on all platforms.  When that is the case, your first keystatus call will return false and the rest of the keystatus conditional logic will be skipped.